# When I activate venv, bash works wrong on PyCharm

Tags: git, pycharm, virtual-environment

I'm setting PyCharm with making virtual environment and git branch.

I checked out from 'master' branch to my branch. After that, I activated venv by " . venv/Scripts/activate".

Then my branch disappeared (I think it's checked out) as you see, and other commands don't work right. (ex. git commands) Yellow box is about what I'm saying

[image: screenshot of terminal]

How can I solve this?

Comment: This post needs clarification. What you are saying seems to not be PyCharm issue, but a `git-bash` issue. So what is the PyCharm issue? Perhaps there are two issues?

Answer (score 0):

(Note: this should logically be a comment, but it's too long to fit as a comment, plus I want some formatting that I can't get that way.)

The venv `activate` script works by modifying environment variables and your shell's `$PATH` setting (or `$path`, lowercase, if using csh/tcsh).  The *goal* of this modification is that `python` will run the correct Python binary, which will then find the correct Python libraries, all via the path and environment settings.  Nothing *else* should change.

It looks as though your particular venv activation script has modified your path such that the `git` command is no longer *on* that path.  That is, something that *should not* have changed, *did* change.  The fix will be to examine the activation script, find where it does something bad to your particular shell—whatever shell that may be—and come up with a modification to some setting somewhere, or a revised activation script, so that the overall result plays well with your shell.

The first part of doing all of this lies in determining which shell you're using and, if versions of that shell matter, which *version* you're using as well.